# Numpy issue while pushing a request to flask app from python

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I have been experiencing this problem while testing my flask app. kindly help

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

Error occurs have doing this code on python

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict",
    json={"sepal_length": 5.1, "sepal_width": 3.5, "petal_length": 1.4, "petal_width": 0.2}
)

print(response.json())
```

I tried following the instructions given by the error, but it still solves nothing

Comment: full error message - with traceback

Comment: I doubt if the flask-app and `requests` is raising the error.  They don't use `numpy`.  However the backend code may be using a module that has not been updated to use the current `numpy` version.  You don't provide enough information to evlauate that.